# Launch a UIPopover on click of a button inside UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

On the left swipe of a row in my Table view, I have two UITableViewRowAction buttons (Delete and More). On the click of **More** button, I am presenting an UIActionSheet with two buttons named **Edit NickName** and **Edit Photo** something like this:

[image]

Now I am trying to launch a UIPopover on click of Edit NickName. For that I am using the following code:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];    

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Edit NickName"]) {
        NSLog(@"Edit NickName");
        UIStoryboard *secondStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SplitView" bundle:nil];
        EditNickNameViewController *popVC = [secondStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditNickNameViewController"];

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popVC];
        popover.delegate=self;
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 300);
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(20,20, 0, 0) inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];



    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Edit Image"]) {
        NSLog(@"Edit Image");
    }
}
```

The above code works very well inside IBAction of any normal UIButton , but it is not showing any popover in this case.

The above lines of code is getting executed at runtime, but nothing is happening.

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to do something like this or am I doing any mistake here. If it is not possible, please suggest me an alternative to how to launch something like a popover on click of **Edit NickName** button.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't supposed to pass `0` for the permitted directions and you certainly shouldn't be passing a zero sized rect to present from. Why not pass the rect and view for the cell?

Comment: @ rmaddy I am passing `0` for the permitted directions because I don't want any associated direction. And I have tried changing size of rectangle but still it is not working. Anyway same code worked inside a action of a normal button in UI.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the `20,20` origin is under the navbar.

Comment: Tried all combination of rectangle parameter. But, it is not working. I guess problem is with UIActionsheet button.

Comment: Instead of using the `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate, try using the `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method. The problem could be trying to show the popover before the action sheet has been dismissed.

Comment: BTW - it's a bad idea to branch on button title text. Labels change (leading to bugs) and it totally fails if you localize your app to other languages.

Comment: Tried it inside `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` and `willDismissWithButtonIndex:` , but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Present your popover on main queue;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(20,20, 0, 0) inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
    });
```

Comment: The OP is already using the main queue. The action sheet delegate methods are always called on the main queue.